# Existence of entire function with simple zeros satisfying that estimate.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $u(z) = u(Re z)$ - piecewise linear function, $x_k$ are points of derivative's leaps, is there entire function $f(z)$ with simple zeros, satisfying $|u(z)-\ln|f(z)||=O(\ln(z)), |z| \rightarrow \infty$ almost everywhere except countable set of circles, wherein
$$
\ln |f(z)|-u(z)=\int_\mathbb{C}\ln\left|1-\frac{z}{w}\right|d(\nu(w)-\mu(w))
$$
$\nu$ is Riesz measure of $\ln |f(z)|$, and $\mu(w)$ is Riesz measure of $u(z)$?